# Can I get the sign of the number using xpath

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I want to get the sign of a number using XPath. Is there a built in function or workaround in Xpath.

As an example : when I pass -3.23 it should return "-" and for 3.23 it should return "+"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring

Comment: @MarcB How should this work with positive numbers?

Comment: Can I get the absolute value of the number ?

Comment: Yes, XPath 2.0 has [abs()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-abs), but you can simply compare to 0 and use `if then` to return `+` or `-`  as I show in the [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29851544/2900850).

Comment: What about 0? Should it return + or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
'+'[$x ge 0], '-'[$x lt 0]
```

where $x is the number, whose sign is wanted.

**This is shorter and might be slightly more efficient** (having only a single comparison):

```
('+'[$x ge 0], '-')[1]
```

---

**Use this XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
substring('+-', 2 - ($x  >= 0), 1)
```

**Explanation**:
The expression produces a substring of the string `'+-'` with length 1 and offset determined by `2 - ($x  >= 0)` -- where we use the fact that in XPath 1.0, if a Boolean value is an argument of an arithmetic operation, `true()` is converted to `1` and `false()` is converted to `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the implied sign by comparing the number to `0`:

```
if ($num >= 0) then '+' else '-'
```